# numbering overwrites equation

Tags: equations, numbering

I have an issue with the numbering of my equations which overwrites in part them

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\nc}{\newcommand}
\nc{\RR}{\mathrm{R}}
\newcommand{\roim}[1]{\RR{#1}_*}
\newcommand{\opb}[1]{#1^{-1}}
\newcommand{\ltens}[1][]{\mathbin{\otimes_{\raise1.5ex\hbox to-.1em{}#1}^{L}}}
\newcommand{\etens}{\mathbin{\boxtimes}}
\newcommand{\letens}{\overset{\mathrm{L}}{\etens}}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:some_equation}
    \begin{array}{l}
        \roim{p_{14\pi}}\circ\opb{^{t}p_{1234}'}\circ\roim{^{t}j'}\circ\opb{j_{\pi}}\simeq\roim{p_{3\pi}}\circ\opb{^{t}p_{3}'}\circ\roim{p_{134\pi}}\circ\opb{^{t}p_{2}'}\circ\roim{^{t}h'}\circ\opb{h_{\pi}}\circ\roim{^{t}k'}\circ\opb{k_{\pi}}
    \end{array}%
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

here is how it looks like

[image]

Someone has an idea on how I can get rid of this ?

Comment: It seems your equation is just to long (53.98pt to wide when I compile it), so I guess the right way to do it would be to break it on multiple lines? Is that something you could do or do you really need every part of this equation to be on a single line?

Comment: @Vinzza thank you for your answer, indeed I need that the equation lies in a single line. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: You can have no number with `\[ ... \]`!

Comment: @Bernard indeed, I just wrote this for short. I edited my post

Comment: Can't you use slightly shorter margins? Just loading `geometry` solves the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explain @pgrass in his answer (+1), your equation is to long for your page layout and is enclosed into `array` which cause overwriting equation number.

For resolving your problem you have more possibilities:

- write equation in two lines (the first example in image)
- use smaller font for equation (the second example in image)
- increase text width in your document
- for equation locally increase text width (the third example in image)

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage[strict]{changepage} % new

\newcommand{\RR}{\mathrm{R}}
\newcommand{\roim}[1]{\RR{#1}_*}
\newcommand{\opb}[1]{#1^{-1}}
\newcommand{\ltens}[1][]{\mathbin{\otimes_{\raise1.5ex\hbox to-.1em{}#1}^{L}}}
\newcommand{\etens}{\mathbin{\boxtimes}}
\newcommand{\letens}{\overset{\mathrm{L}}{\etens}}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
\label{eq:some_equation}
    \roim{p_{14\pi}}\circ\opb{^{t}p_{1234}'}\circ\roim{^{t}j'}\circ\opb{j_{\pi}}    \\
        \simeq\roim{p_{3\pi}}\circ\opb{^{t}p_{3}'}\circ\roim{p_{134\pi}}\circ\opb{^{t}p_{2}'}\circ\roim{^{t}h'}\circ\opb{h_{\pi}}\circ\roim{^{t}k'}\circ\opb{k_{\pi}}
\end{multline}

{\footnotesize
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:some_equation}
    \roim{p_{14\pi}}\circ\opb{^{t}p_{1234}'}\circ\roim{^{t}j'}\circ\opb{j_{\pi}}   
        \simeq\roim{p_{3\pi}}\circ\opb{^{t}p_{3}'}\circ\roim{p_{134\pi}}\circ\opb{^{t}p_{2}'}\circ\roim{^{t}h'}\circ\opb{h_{\pi}}\circ\roim{^{t}k'}\circ\opb{k_{\pi}}
\end{equation}
}

\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-5em}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:some_equation}
    \roim{p_{14\pi}}\circ\opb{^{t}p_{1234}'}\circ\roim{^{t}j'}\circ\opb{j_{\pi}}
        \simeq\roim{p_{3\pi}}\circ\opb{^{t}p_{3}'}\circ\roim{p_{134\pi}}\circ\opb{^{t}p_{2}'}\circ\roim{^{t}h'}\circ\opb{h_{\pi}}\circ\roim{^{t}k'}\circ\opb{k_{\pi}}
\end{equation}
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Comment: +1. Speaking for myself, I'd say that the `multline`-based solution is best.

Comment: @Mico, thank you! For me too, so I put it on the first place :-)

Answer (score 3):

The formula is too wide. Use `multline`, which is made just for such problems.

I also changed the definition of `\opb` adding a pair of braces, so not to risk an initial exponent is set to the `\circ`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\RR}{\mathrm{R}}
\newcommand{\roim}[1]{\RR{#1}_*}
\newcommand{\opb}[1]{{}#1^{-1}}
\newcommand{\ltens}[1][]{\mathbin{\otimes_{\raise1.5ex\hbox to-.1em{}#1}^{L}}}
\newcommand{\etens}{\mathbin{\boxtimes}}
\newcommand{\letens}{\overset{\mathrm{L}}{\etens}}


\begin{document}

\begin{multline}\label{eq:some_equation}
\roim{p_{14\pi}}\circ\opb{^{t}p_{1234}'}\circ\roim{^{t}j'}\circ\opb{j_{\pi}} \\
\simeq\roim{p_{3\pi}}\circ\opb{^{t}p_{3}'}\circ\roim{p_{134\pi}}\circ
  \opb{^{t}p_{2}'}\circ\roim{^{t}h'}\circ\opb{h_{\pi}}\circ\roim{^{t}k'}\circ\opb{k_{\pi}}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

I'm still quite doubtful about the definition of `\ltens`.

[image]

By the way, `\boxtimes` is defined as a `\mathbin`, so you can simply do

```
\newcommand{\etens}{\boxtimes}
```

You can also remove `\mathbin` from the definition of `\ltens` (and the braces, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Well your equation is too long for one line and the numbering. I don't quite understand why you use \begin{array} instead of \begin{equation}.
If you don't want the number you could use \begin{equation*}. If you want your eaution split into two lines you can use the \begin{align} and then \begin{split}.
But i'm quite new to latex and others probably have better ideas.